# Combine two .tex files

Tags: titles, document-classes, include

I'm making my phd dissertation in LaTeX. Although I am a noob, everything works like a charm, but now I have to make the titlepage. My university had a LaTeX `.tex` file (with `.sty` file,...) which produces a titlepage.

I tried to include this titlepage with `\include`, but it won't work. Probably since both have a different documentclass etc. Is there any possibility to make one single `.tex` file (which refers to the titlepage `.tex` file?)

Comment: You can't merge document classes like that but most title page definitions are not that complicated, a few font size and spacing commands and perhaps a logo or two. It probably isn't that hard to add the relevant definitions to the preamble of your existing document. Hard to give details with no information though.

Comment: indeed, that did the trick. Not difficult at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can format code by using the `{}` button in the edit window.

Comment: @pieter glad you got it working, if that's it we'll probably close the question as too localised as we don't like to leave questions unanswered.

Comment: Note that you can also include a page (or some pages, or all) of an *existing* pdf file in your LaTeX document using the `pdfpages` package.